# Product of discontinuous and smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a smooth function (i.e. $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$), $g$ discontinuous in some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and smooth everywhere else, for example $g(x)=\Theta(x)$ or $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Furthermore, $fg\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I want to show, that this already implies, that all partial derivatives of $f$ vanish at $x_0$.

Intuitively, this seems right as $f$ has to smooth out $g$ at $x_0$. One can easliy show, that $f(x_0)=0$: assume the contrary, then $g=\frac{fg}{f}$ would be smooth at $x_0$, which contradicts the assumption. However, this trick does not work for derivatives. I also tried fooling around with some limits, didn't get to anything substantial so far.

I still think, that this has to be quite elementary. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: With $g(x) = {1 \over x} $ and $f(x) = x$ we have $fg=1$, but the partials of $f$ do not vanish.

Comment: Ah, crap, that seems to be true. Guess I'll need to search for more conditions then. Thank you!